# Laravel Implicit Controller pagination

Tags: laravel-4

I have one of routes defined like this in laravel routes file.

```
Route::controller('login/home/admin/', 'AdminController');
```

But it seems laravel pagination does not work in methods. So i changed Route to allow `page` variable like this in one of the methods.

```
Route::get('login/home/admin/users/{page}', 'AdminController@getUsers');
Route::controller('login/home/admin/', 'AdminController');
```

Now problem is `login/home/admin/users/2` loads but pagination does not work and if I try this `login/home/admin/users?page=2` I am redirected.

**EDIT:**

My method is defined like this and does not work.

```
public function getUsers(){
   var_dump( Input::get('page') ); // Returns NULL
   $users = User::paginate(10);
   ...
   ...
}
```

and in view

```
...
{{ $users->links() }}
...
```

This view generates pagination but only first page works. Page 2 and other pages show records of page 1.

I doubt its because `Input::get('page')` is not working for some reason.

**EDIT 2**

None of following routes worked for me.

```
Route::get('login/home/admin/users/', 'AdminController@getUsers');
Route::controller('login/home/admin/', 'AdminController');
```

and

```
Route::get('login/home/admin/users/{page}', 'AdminController@getUsers');
Route::controller('login/home/admin/', 'AdminController');
```

and

```
Route::controller('login/home/admin/', 'AdminController');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok this was something silly in htaccess that was not letting ?page=x or any other GET variable pass to code. Compared my htaccess to real htaccess of Laravel 4.2 and there was something different.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]  <-- CULPRIT
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Route to

```
Route::get('login/home/admin/users/', 'AdminController@getUsers');
```

Laravel Pagination automatically takes care of your page variable in request
Here is the extract for Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination):

> There are several ways to paginate items. The simplest is by using the
>   paginate method on the query builder or an Eloquent query. The
>   paginate method provided by Laravel automatically takes care of
>   setting the proper limit and offset based on the current page being
>   viewed by the user. By default, the current page is detected by the
>   value of the ?page query string argument on the HTTP request. Of
>   course, this value is automatically detected by Laravel, and is also
>   automatically inserted into links generated by the paginator.

Comment: thanks for replying. I saw that but it does not fix my issue. I added more info to my question.

Comment: what link does `{{ $users->links() }}` is generating. I mean exact link

Comment: it generates paging but paging is stuck at page 1 always. When i click on page 2 link becomes SITNAME/login/home/admin/users?page=2 but shows same content as SITNAME/login/home/admin/users.

Comment: what is your current route ? `users/` or `users/{page}`

Comment: Route::get('login/home/admin/users/', 'AdminController@getUsers');
Route::controller('login/home/admin/', 'AdminController');

also tried
Route::get('login/home/admin/users/{page}', 'AdminController@getUsers');
Route::controller('login/home/admin/', 'AdminController');

and
Route::controller('login/home/admin/', 'AdminController');

Comment: check Edit 2 in my question now.